# How to change the Android softkey keyboard "Go" button to "Next"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a **WebView** which has a form containing 10 editboxes. When I type in an editbox I find that in the softkey keyboard **Go** button is visible which eventually takes me to the next page. But I want **Next** button which should take me to the next editbox, not to the next page. So, how to change the softkey keyboard "Go" button to "Next" in Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the xml, specifiy for your editboxes the attribute `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` .
The next button will bring the user into the next field that accept input.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html which may help you.