# How do I customize imeoptions for text boxes of web form developed for Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webform that is integrated into a native app via a webview. But now when the user sets the focus on the first textbox of the form, I see a Go button on the soft keyboard. Instead, I'd like to have Next button, clicking on which would take me to the next input control. And the last input control alone should have Go button on keyboard. How do I achieve this? (Note: Please note that I want this on a web form. I've already found material on how to do this on a native form.)

Answer (score 0):

Please go to take a look, is that what you are looking for?

[How to change the Android softkey keyboard "Go" button to "Next"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327886/how-to-change-the-softkey-keyboard-go-button-to-next-android)