# HTML: Why does Android browser show "Go" instead of "Next" in keyboard?

Tags: android, html, browser, android-softkeyboard

I have an HTML login form that contains following elements (in this order):

- `input type=text` (user name input)
- `input type=password` (password)
- `input type=submit` (Login button)

Why does the Android browser show "Go" button in soft keyboard instead of "Next" button when the focus is in the `text input`? This causes user to fail to login very easily because after entering the user name, the user presses the bottom right button in the keyboard (usually the correct action) and the form will be submitted with an empty password, which obviously is not going to work. [This behavior would make sense in case my browser was set to remember passwords and the password manager would be able to fill in the password. However, this is not the case here as you can test yourself below.]

I'd like to have the input type text to have "Next" button and the input type password (the last input before the submit) to have the "Go" button.

An example of problematic form is at https://peda.net/:login (this form contains code to detect "Enter" key for the input and prevents submitting the form unless the last visible form input is focused).

Do you know a real fix for this issue? I know that if I were implementing native application, I'd use `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` (see [How to change the Android softkey keyboard "Go" button to "Next"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327886/how-to-change-the-softkey-keyboard-go-button-to-next-android)). However, in this case it's an HTML form and Android default browser.

The problem is visible with at least following configurations:

- "Browser" system app running on Android 2.3.4 (Cyanogenmod 7)
- "Browser" system app running on Android 4.2.2 (Cyanogenmod 10.1)
- "Browser" system app running on Android 4.3.1 (Cyanogenmod 10.2 M1)
- "Browser" system app (AOSP Browser) running on Android 4.4.2 (Cyanogenmod 11.0 M3)
- "Browser" system app (AOSP Browser) running on Android 5.5.1 (Cyanogenmod 12.1) [has an arrow icon instead of word "Go"]
- "Browser" system app (AOSP Browser) running on Android 6.0.1 (Cyanogenmod 13.0) [has an arrow icon instead of word "Go"]

Comment: Have you tried using tabindex on the inputs?

Comment: The question intrigued me so I tried tabindex, didn't work though.

Comment: I wonder if this is misbehavior is still state of the art?

Comment: The problem is still visible with AOSP browser running on Android 4.3.1 - I've updated the question with the latest info.

Comment: This is still happening in Chrome 35 on Android 4.4.2. Is this actually a Chrome/AOSP/Webkit bug or is it the keyboard? Who do we report the bug to? So strange that this rather frustrating UX problem has had so little coverage in over 3 years, especially when iOS has done it right for longer than that.

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem; its showing "next" when I want a "go". I ended up adding a button to the form

Comment: According to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410785 this should be fixed once Google Chrome 62 gets distributed to Android systems. No word about AOSP browser yet. (It's a shame this has taken 6 years to fix!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the Chromium issue if you want to watch it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410785

Here is a workaround for Android that changes the "enter" in the user input so that it "tabs" to the password field (and doesn't submit the form):

http://jsbin.com/zakeza/1/quiet

```
<form action="?">
  User <input type=text onkeypress=key(event)><br><br>
  Password <input id=pw type=password><br><br>
  <input type=submit>
</form>

<script>
  function key(event) {
    if (event.charCode == 13 && /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById('pw').focus();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Edit: Note Windows Phone also puts `Android` into the UA, so needs testing that works on Windows Phone (and Android Firefox).

Answer (score 59):

To add to John's answer, Android always adds 'Go' to text inputs *and always adds 'Next' to number inputs*. I'd love to hear the person responsible for this choice explain their logic.

The softkeyboard design is just lousy in this respect, because every user I've tested with so far has thought the big blue button in the keyboard must be the button that takes you to the next form field and then at the last form field lets you submit the form.

iOS it's even worse in this respect, since they offer a 'Go' button with every form field and no way to tab through the fields. It's nice that Apple likes to make computers simple for people, but sometimes assuming that people like it simple can shade into presuming people are all idiots.

Sorry about that rant. I do have something constructive to offer:

If your last form field happens to be type=number, then there is a tiny hack that will work on Android as well as iOS: add an invisible text input to the form with `onfocus="$('#thisForm').submit();"`. In Android this field will briefly flash into view: in iOS it wont. To make the Android situation more palatable, you can either set a value for the text input like "Closing this form", or you can set its width to 0, which will cause the form field to be not quite 0 width but still very small.

Horrible hack, but hey, blame it on the UI people at Google and Apple.

Comment: Or you could position the input off-screen with position:absolute; left:-9999px; or something like that.

Comment: iOS keyboard has "next" and "previous" buttons, they're shown as up/down arrows on the top left corner of the keyboard.

Comment: Nice answer and nice rant, it captured my own feelings quite well. I do have one issue with the hack, though: won't the form be submitted on a desktop browser if the user presses the Tab key?

Comment: I had to use Ivy's suggestion of positioning the element off-screen, unfortunately hiding the input properly means you can't tab to it.

Comment: Did this behaviour change? After latest webview update, my app stopped showing the Next button for number inputs. It always shows Go button.

Answer (score 23):

The Android Browser always displays Go for input fields because some forms on the web (especially search boxes) have no submit button, and can only be activated by pressing Enter (Go is equivalent to Enter).

Instead some versions of Android will show a tab key in the bottom right of the keyboard to facilitate navigating between form fields.

I don't think you can prevent either of these behaviours.

Two possible workarounds:

1. Use JavaScript to ignore submission of the login form until both inputs are non-blank:

   ```
   <form name="loginForm" onsubmit="return document.loginForm.user.value != '' && document.loginForm.pass.value != ''">
       <input type="text" name="user">
       <input type="password" name="pass">
       <input type="submit" value="Login">
   </form>
   ```
2. The cleanest solution would be to set both inputs to be required using the new HTML5 [required attribute](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required) - **but** the Android Browser doesn't support this yet. However a good approach would be to supplement the required attribute with a JavaScript fallback such as that [described by CSSKarma](http://www.csskarma.com/blog/required-input-fallback/).

Answer (score 6):

I was having this problem, and then I realized that I had forgot to wrap everything in a `<form>` element. That fixed everything.

Answer (score 5):

see [Replace Go button on soft keyboard with Next in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470439/replace-go-button-on-soft-keyboard-with-next-in-phonegap).

For a quick navigation see this [plunker](http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/Gxbhm).
To follow complete code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" id="form">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <select name="select" readonly="readonly">
  <option>Select Something</option>
  </select>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" disabled="disabled">
Select <select name="select" id="selectBox">
               <option>Select Something</option>
       </select>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Select <select name="select" readonly="readonly">
  <option>Select Something</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>

<script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.enterAsTab = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            'allowSubmit': false
        }, options);
        $(this).find('input, select, textarea, button').live("keydown", {localSettings: settings}, function(event) {
            if (settings.allowSubmit) {
                var type = $(this).attr("type");
                if (type == "submit") {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])");
                var idx = inputs.index(this);
                if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
                    idx = -1;
                } else {
                    inputs[idx + 1].focus(); // handles submit buttons
                }
                try {
                    inputs[idx + 1].select();
                }
                catch (err) {

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#form").enterAsTab({ 'allowSubmit': true});
</script>
```

NOTE: don't forget to replace `.live()` method of jquery with `.on()` if using newer version of jquery than 1.9.

Comment: Great answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the button to be 'Go' always use:
enterKeyHint="Go"

see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71593469/2721727

Comment: Great info! See the support matrix and documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/enterkeyhint

Answer (score 1):

You can generically change ENTER keys into input elements into focussing the next input, using pure JavaScript.

It is not only useful in mobile browsers, but in desktop browsers too.

You can refine it for textarea and select.

```
function keyControls(e) {

    // [enter] on inputs tranformed into focus next input.
    // Sending events to inputs is security forbidden.
    // We find the next element and focus() it.
    //    optionally restrict to certain user agens: && /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent)
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        var el = document.activeElement;
        if (el.tagName == "INPUT" || el.tagName == "SELECT") {

            e.preventDefault();
            var nextEl = null;    
            var found = false;
            for (var i = 0, element; element = el.form.elements[i++];) {
                if (element.type !== "hidden" && element.type !== "fieldset" ) {
                    if (found) {
                        nextEl = element;
                        console.log("found next    element", element.name, " at ", i);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (el === element) {
                        console.log("found current element", element.name, " at ", i);
                        found = true;
                    }
                    // console.log("iterating form elements", element.name, " to ", i);
                } else {
                    // console.log("iterating form elements - skipping ", element.name, " - ", i);
                }
            }
            if (nextEl && nextEl.focus) nextEl.focus();


            if (nextEl) {
                console.log("key listener ENTER - transformed into TAB:", el.tagName, el.name, nextEl.tagName, nextEl.name );
            } else {
                console.log("key listener ENTER - transformed into TAB:", el.tagName, el.name, " next element not found" );
            }


        } else {
            console.log("key listener ENTER on tagname:", el.tagName, el.name );
        }
    }

}

window.onload = function () {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyControls, false);
    console.log("key listener registered");                
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion for user let GO button function as enter button only.

For this use a form tag but to avoid incomplete submissions use disabled attribute on submit button.

```
$("input:not(.submit)").bind('input',function(){
var isValid = validateInputs();

if(isValid)
                {
                    $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }

});
```

Now To avoid page reload dont use action or onsubmit attributes in form tag, instead use

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){

var disabled=$('.submit').attr('disabled');
                if(disabled=='disabled')
                {
                    return;
                }

callOnSubmitFunction();
return false;
}
);
```

return false is important here to avoid page reload.

with the exception of chrome, the firefox and the default android browsers show a prev and next buttons which will work as tab buttons, so use proper tabindex atrributes on form input element.

Answer (score 0):

We can not prevent this default behavior because there is not input `type="next"` tag available in HTML as of now. So by default "Go" button appears. Below link having list of available input type tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: The "Go" button appearing seems totally arbitrary. It always shows "Go" button if input type is `text` and it always shows "Next" if input type is `number`. I personally consider this behavior as a bug which never gets fixed for some unknown reason - perhaps Google is afraid to change the status quo or Google does not consider this important enough to invest the engineering effort to fix AOSP browser because they think everybody should use Chrome. Chrome on Android seems to always show "Next" instead of "Go" if a form contains more than a single text input.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, This is not a Google's bug or we can say HTML should add this feature. After reading your this comment I verified on Nexus5 Chrome browser. Behavior is same i.e. no next button appears. I tried to login to Facebook from Chrome, when I entered username then no "Next" option appeared. As I mentioned that this feature should be added in HTML because this behavior is same even on Desktop. You can't go to next edit field using "arrow keys" on Tab works because  type="tab" is available.

Comment: Yeah, the info I had about Chrome was incorrect (I was using a localized keyboard and guessed wrong which localization meant "Go"). Chrome seems to show Go button, too, for this case. I still think that HTML already has all the required features for this case. For example, it has `tabindex` (http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.tabindex) which should be more than enough to hint the browser that more form items follow before the submit button should be used. However, actual browser implementation is not high quality enough to consider such attributes.

Comment: I think that a browser would do fine if it displayed "Next" for all form fields except if the next form element is a submit button, then the "Go" button would be okay. I would prefer just focusing the submit button even in that case and requiring me to confirm the actual form submission.

Comment: @mikko-rantalainen The Android team seem to have written code to deal with that https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410785#c32 although I am skeptical they will fix this problem.