# Unable to move focus to a non input type field in a form

Tags: android, html, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

For HTML5 form, I have 4 fields in this order:

- amount(input type text)
- currency(select tag)
- date(input type date) and
- comments(textarea)

When the user enters the `amount` and hit the `next` button from soft keyboard, the focus goes to `comments` instead. I want it to go to `currency` field and display options. How can I do that? Or is there a way I can remove next button from the Android and BlackBerry keyboard's particular page?

Answer (score 0):

This differs between Android versions and the type of keyboard the user uses...

How do you display a `Next` button in the soft keyboard in Android when using `input type="text"`? AFAIK that's not possible([1](http://japborst.net/posts/android-forms-next-button), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard))... as it is displayed only for `input type="number"`. For text it displays a `Go` button instead.

That said, perhaps you can try using the `tabindex` attribute. Should help in controlling the form navigation order.
I didn't try it in a mobile device with its keyboard, though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" tabindex="1"/>
            <select tabindex="2">
                <option value="option1">option1</option>
                <option value="option2">option2</option>
                <option value="option3">option3</option>
                <option value="option4">option4</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" tabindex="3"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You may also opt to create a native form in which case you can [easily control the navigation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard). However as for BlackBerry I don't know (you also do not mention if it is the exact same behavior in both or not...).