# Cordova Android Text Input Next Focus

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have noticed that in an Android Cordova project anything with `<input type="number">` includes a "next" button on the keyboard. This next button allows you to focus on the next input field when pressed. The same is not true for a `<input type="text">`. In this case there is only a 'go' button and it does not do anything. How can I set focus to the next input field when inside a input text field? Thanks!

I am using Android Kit Kat with Cordova 3.3

UPDATE: I have found that it is possible to make the "next" button appear in Android by setting the `android:imeOption` inside of `<EditText android:imeOptions="actionNext"> </EditText>`. Is there a way to set that option in cordova?

Comment: Have you set the tabIndex property for all of your inputs?

Comment: I tried that, however it does not work. Thanks for your input!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML: Why does Android browser show "Go" instead of "Next" in keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard)

Comment: @jam That has more to do with browsers on Android. I am trying to find a way through the cordova framework to achieve this setting. I have found that it is possible to make the "next" button appear in Android by setting the `android:imeOption` inside of `<EditText android:imeOptions="actionNext"> </EditText>`. I am looking for a way to set that option in cordova.

Comment: Cordova is a wrapper for the Android browser (*WebView). If you want custom EditText fields, you will need to write a plugin. Doing what you are asking may not even be possible with a plugin. Depending on your exact requirements, it could get complicated very quickly.