# How to detect pressing enter on mobile device keyboard using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.When press enter in textbox ,open Modal popup with Bootstrap.But when I using mobile phone ,I cant detect pressing enter.How to detect it ?Can you help me please?
My code ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

           $('.form-control').keyup(function (e) {
               if (e.which == 13)   {      
                   $('.modal').modal('show');
               }
           });

       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in javascript console? Your sure that `modal()` is defined when code executes?

Answer (score 7):

Normally, within a form, the enter key on a mobile device submits the form. I suggest adding some logic in a submit handler:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
      // you're logic here
}
```

**Additional information**

See: [HTML: Why does Android browser show "Go" instead of "Next" in keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard)

Comment: @GlenSwift, may I suggest some reading? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard

Answer (score -1):

Well, on touch devices there is no such event as `keyup` as far as I know. At least in iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

Consider using form's `submit` event instead.