# Android keyboard shows "Go" key not "next" after fill an input type

Tags: android, jquery, css, html, mobile

I have a contact form with 5 "input" text. Say the first is the "name", Android keyboard appears to write, when you finished, you need to go to the next input field, usually there is a key ("next") to take you fast and inside the next input. However in my case, there is no "next" key, it's just the "Go" key, this sends all the form to the server. How can I control this ?

Comment: Give android:imeOptions="actionNext" to your editext or give  android:singleline = true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML: Why does Android browser show "Go" instead of "Next" in keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25651603/3221274

Answer (score 1):

set

```
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

in your  tag

Comment: dup or not, terse response or not, your answer led me to the right thing. I'll undo one of those "nothing better to do but vote people down all day on SO." down votes.