# go to next field automatically html5 form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am using following html5 form.

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="orderno" />
 <input name="picture" id="img" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
 <input class="btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

When I open this page in my mobile phone, I want that When I fill first input text, there should be a button called "NEXT" in my keyboard but currently it shows "GO" button directly. Any Help please?

javascript function `document.getElementById('img').focus();` is not opening camera automatically.

I want the facility to launch camera on phone automatically when clicked "NEXT" or "GO" in keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: Why does Android browser show "Go" instead of "Next" in keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard)

Comment: Edited my question with specific requirement. Please check out now.

Comment: So is your question how to get Next instead of Go, or is your question how to launch the camera after Next or Go is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Security concerns, most browsers do not allow direct access to file uploader or image capture trigger. User has to click on the corresponding field to upload file or capture photograph. you can define focus after each has been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

In first input have `tabindex='1'` in second input have `tabindex='2'` and so on.