# Show <Go> instead of <Next> in Chrome soft keyboard for input type="number"

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, mobile

It seems <Go> is displayed for all input types except for type="number".

1. Is there any way to make this behavior consistent for all input types without adding an additional button and making sure that **soft keyboard displays numbers only**?

I've tried setting it to input type="text" then setting the pattern and inputmode attributes, but still no luck (non-numeric buttons are shown in the keyboard).

2. Is this an open bug in Chrome? If so, do you have the bug link detailing the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. It' s a bug in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410785

Duplicate of: [HTML: Why does Android browser show "Go" instead of "Next" in keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545086/html-why-does-android-browser-show-go-instead-of-next-in-keyboard)