# HTML <input type=“number”>, for mobile devices enter key not working

Tags: android, html, jquery, mobile-chrome, numeric-keypad

I've got a single line of code (no forms involved) here:

```
<input name="txtQty" type="number" id="txtQty" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d*">
```

Tried the below code to get the keycode to know that enter key pressed:

```
$("#txtQty").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("enter");
    }
});
```

When clicking on the Next button it's a move to the next input element instead of fire keyup event:

[image]

Is there any way to press the next button on the keyboard and get that to execute my other javascript function?

Comment: If you do `alert(e.key)` on mobile, what do you get? Or you don't get anything at all

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, When clicking on the Next button, it just ignores the keyup event and moves the curser to the next element.

Comment: Than the mobile browser (on *"Next"*) uses eventually some sort of tabIndexing... Not sure but perhaps a solution would be to trigger something on `"blur"` Event instead? And some interesting read : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026173/383904

Comment: It's a little more overhead .. But you might try `$(document).on('keyup', '#txtQty', function(){`  It seems to me this a a little more "universal" ?

Comment: @Zak how did you get to that conclusion? Any mention of dynamicity?

Comment: Why not bind to the `change` event instead of `keyup`?

Comment: Why do you think `[next]` == `[enter]`?   It's most likely `[tab]`.  You don't get key up for tab as it's already changed input before you keyup,  Short answer: don't use keyup (maybe keydown?)