# Sencha touch keyboard next button on xtype textfield

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Following is my Sencha code of a simple registration form:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
items: [
    {
        name: 'name',
        id: 'rename',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        placeHolder: 'Name*',
        tabIndex: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'emailfield',
        id: 'reemailid',
        xtype: 'emailfield',
        placeHolder: 'email@example.com*',
        tabIndex: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'password',
        id: 'repassword',
        xtype: 'passwordfield',
        placeHolder: 'Password*',
        tabIndex: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'confpassword',
        id: 'reconfpassword',
        xtype: 'passwordfield',
        placeHolder: 'Confirm Password*',
        tabIndex: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'address',
        id: 'readdress',
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        placeHolder: 'Address*',
        tabIndex: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'dob',
        id: 'redob',
        placeHolder: 'Date Of Birth',
        xtype: 'datepickerfield',
        destroyPickerOnHide: true,
        picker: {
            yearFrom: 1960
        },
        tabIndex: 6
    }
]
```

When I am filling up the form in Android keyboard there is a 'Go' button in bottom right corner of the android keyboard, which helps us to submit the form. But I want a 'Next' button which will take me to the next field, I mean if I filled the name and press the 'Next' button on Android keyboard then it should take me to email.

Comment: Are making this app for android?

Answer (score 0):

The `action` event is triggered on a `textfield` whenever the "Return" or "Go" key is pressed. You should leverage that to call the `focus` method on the next field.

Something like this will work on Android, didn't test it on iOS though

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.Main', {

    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'First field',
                listeners: {
                    action: function() {
                        Ext.getCmp('field_2').focus();
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'field_2',
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'Second field'
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Working example at: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=b3o#fiddle/b3o

[EDIT]

Previous solution remains valid but I found this linked question:

[How to change the Android softkey keyboard "Go" button to "Next"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327886/how-to-change-the-android-softkey-keyboard-go-button-to-next).

This is done on the native Android project and modifies the behavior of the "Go" button application wide. Check it out.